# Inconsistent results with unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, file-io

I'm writing a program and there is a specific function that gives me inconsistent results. If I run it the first time, it will evaluate to "already in blacklist, skipping...", however the second time I run it it doesn't evaluate to this. Every time I re-execute the code after this, it will follow the exact same pattern.

```
void BruteBlock::get_blacklist(std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& r, const std::string& output_file) {
    std::ifstream is(output_file.c_str());

    if (!is) throw std::invalid_argument("Error opening blacklist");

    // ignore duplicates
    std::string buf;
    while(std::getline(is, buf)) {
        if (r.find(buf) != r.end()) {
            r.erase(buf);
            std::cout << buf << " already in blacklist, skipping..." << '\n';
        }
    }

    for(auto a = r.begin(); a != r.end(); ++a) {
        std::string ip(a->first);
        if (a->second < max_attempts) {
            ++a;
            r.erase(ip);
        }
        else {
            if (a->second > max_attempts) {
                if (check_reports(a->first) < max_reports) {
                    ++a;
                    r.erase(ip);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    is.close();

    // write the remaining IPs to the blacklist
    std::ofstream os(output_file.c_str());

    if (!os) throw std::invalid_argument("Error opening blacklist file");

    for(auto f : r) {
        if ((f.second > max_attempts) && (check_reports(f.first) > max_reports)) {
            os << f.first << '\n';
            std::cout << f.first << " had " << f.second << " failed attempts and " << check_reports(f.first)
                      << " abuse reports, adding to blacklist...\n";
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that it might be because of collision between opening the same file for reading and writing with two different file streams, so I explicitly called is.close(),  however it makes no difference. Between file stream errors and something to do with the map, I can't think of any other problem. It also seems as if nothing gets written to the file where it says os << f.first << '\n', yet it will print the text below that line.

For recreating the problem, you can assume that...

- std::unordered_map just has some IPs as keys with numbers as the value
- check_reports simply returns a number
- max_attempts is 5
- max_reports is 2
- the output file already has all of these IPs in the map written line by line

My output:

```
root@vps163169:~/BruteBlock# ./a.out
1.2.3.4 already in blacklist, skipping...
2.3.4.5 already in blacklist, skipping...
3.4.5.6 already in blacklist, skipping...
4.5.6.7 already in blacklist, skipping...
5.6.7.8 already in blacklist, skipping...
6.7.8.9 already in blacklist, skipping...
7.8.9.0 already in blacklist, skipping...
8.9.0.1 already in blacklist, skipping...
9.0.1.2 already in blacklist, skipping...
10.1.2.3 already in blacklist, skipping...
11.2.3.4 already in blacklist, skipping...
root@vps163169:~/BruteBlock# ./a.out
1.2.3.4 had 6 failed attempts and 60 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
2.3.4.5 had 6 failed attempts and 6 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
3.4.5.6 had 7 failed attempts and 18 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
4.5.6.7 had 14 failed attempts and 7 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
5.6.7.8 had 12 failed attempts and 139 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
6.7.8.9 had 20 failed attempts and 213 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
7.8.9.0 had 6 failed attempts and 14 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
8.9.0.1 had 6 failed attempts and 14 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
9.0.1.2 had 6 failed attempts and 12 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
10.1.2.3 had 8 failed attempts and 79 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
11.2.3.4 had 7 failed attempts and 4 abuse reports, adding to blacklist...
```

Comment: There are numerous problems in this code.  You erase things from `r` but you never add anything to it.  The way you're erasing things is wrong, too, since the iterator isn't updated correctly.  Why do you erase things from the blacklist if they're already there?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't need to add anything to r, those are for other functions in my programs. This function needs to ensure that only the keys from the map that aren't already in the output file and have a value of more than max_attempts and a check_reports() of more than max_reports get written to the list. And for the iterator I need to add ++a because I get a segmentation fault if I try to do erase() since the iterator is currently pointing to what I'm erasing

Comment: The proper way to erase would be `a = r.erase(a);`, then not increment `a` that iteration.  With your current way, you're skipping elements, and possibly incrementing `a` past the end of the container.  And you're overwriting the existing content of `output_file` when you update the blacklist.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I can't believe I left out std::ios_base::app!